# Three.js difference between mouseclick and mousemove

Tags: three.js, onmouseover, onmousedown

I am trying to intersect a plane geometry, which is about 3600px X 3600px.

This works fine, while used in an onmousemove- function, but copying and pasting the code, into an onclick- function does only give a result every 10-20 clicks, while the click itself is noticed.

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( intersectables );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    var intersect = intersects[ 0 ];
    console.log( intersects[ 0 ].point.x );
}
```

Once I clicked a point, on that plane geometry, which responses properly on the raycast, I can click it several times and it responds again. Most of the plane-geometry does not, when clicked but charmingly, while overmoused.

Is there any difference, between mousemove and onclick I am not aware ?

Comment: So, when using scene.children, instead of the intersectables Array, the plane registers every click and gives the mouse-on-plane-position, but poorely, when using the Array, still only on some rare points

Comment: Show how you are creating the plane mesh.